# Magento homepage redirects to 404 page not found

Tags: reindex, magento2.3, 404-page, home-page, redirect-url

After **reindexing**, when entering the **homepage url**, I'm redirected to **404 page not found**.
I have checked `configuration/general/web` and everything seems to be working there.

Comment: System->Configuration->general->Web->secure Base URL: http://www.your-site.com/ (be sure you are in the right shop site from the top left of the system)

Comment: System->Configuration->general->Web->Default Pages Default Web URL: cms (yes just cms) CMS Home Page: select your cms page Default No-route URL: cms/index/noRoute

Comment: add .htaccess file in your root folder.